# Why is WinJS.UI.processAll() called automatically for you in Page Controls but not elsewhere?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465493.aspx) explains when to call WinJS.UI.processAll() yourself in your apps and when it's done for you automatically:

> If you aren't using the Blank Application template or if you're adding
> the control to a page that you created yourself, you might need to add
> a call to WinJS.UI.processAll.
>
> - If you added the control to your app's home page (which is usually    the default.html file), add a call to WinJS.UI.processAll in your onactivated event handler, as shown in the previous example.
> - **If you    added the control to a Page control, you don't need to add a call to    WinJS.UI.processAll because the Page control does that for you    automatically.**
> - If you added the control to another page that is not    your app's home page, handle the DOMContentLoaded event and use the    handler to call WinJS.UI.processAll.

What's the reasoning behind the system calling WinJS.UI.processAll() automatically for you inside Page Controls, but not elsewhere?

Comment: Probably because the page control handles a bunch of events for you, check out it's source code in base.js. It adds methods (functions) you can just override, so you don't need to worry about setting up a promise to process the UI. Also, they may have wanted to give you control. If they always called `processAll`, it may interfere with any processing you wanted to do yourself (like custom templating or rendering). Better to let you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It's also because the Navigation template (and the Grid template which is derives from the Navigation template) includes at least one data-win-control element so it needs to be processed to function.
We (Microsoft) don't want to put too much in the blank project template because after all it is "blank". So the blank project template just gives you the single page, no navigation, no controls, and thus no need for any processing. You can decide to add that on your own.

Comment: I understand why you need to call `UI.processAll()` if you've added a data-win-control element to a page, but what I don't understand is what is special about a Page control container (vs. a regular page) that Microsoft would make the call to `processAll()` for you in a Page control but not in a regular page?